# Asterisk console command for getting logged sip users?

Tags: sip, asterisk, asteriskami

Is there any direct console command for getting logged sip users in a particular context

Answer (score 1):

```
asterisk -rx "sip show peers"

asterisk -rx "sip show users"
```

Unfortanly users and contexts are DIFFERENT entities, so no way bind user to context or get that info.

Comment: with the results, it isn't too hard to split the string by '@',  which results in <ext>@<context>.

Comment: not think any of that commands give any @ sign anywhere. maybe you missed with "voicemail show users "?

Comment: This command gives all the sip devices in that asterisk.Do we have any option to get logged in sip clients